# Microsoft Ajax.js:Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null after deployment on live server

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax

I have added registered AjaxControlToolkit on the page .

`<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %`>

then I have Script Manager and Update Panel

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="36000" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
```

Update panels contains the save button

On save button click the data is saved in the database but after save form does not get loaded properly.it gives a JavaScript alert 'Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null in MicrosoftAjax.js'

Please help us with the answers.

Comment: `apply` is a property of `Function.prototype`.  The error means that some code expected to find a function, but that function did not exist.  My first suspicion is that some script is not loading properly.  Do you see any 404 errors in the _Network_ tab of your development tools?  If you have a minimization process, are you sure it is working properly?  Can you verify that you are loading all the scripts that you think you are loading?

Comment: The same code is working fine on my machine but not working when i am hosting the site on iis.I think  there is some problem in AjaxControlToolkit as MicrosoftAjax.js resides inside this        <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %> .

Comment: My advice stands: do you see any 404 errors in the _Network_ tab of your development tools?  Can you verify that you are loading all the scripts that you think you are loading?  The _Network_ tab will list every resource that is loaded for the page.  Compare this list on your machine with the list that appears when you load it on IIS.  What are the differences?

Comment: Chris I have checked in network tab and compared the list as suggested by you.When running from local all files are loading and on Save click data is submitted and all files gets loaded again(working fine).When running application from iis all files are loading and on Save click data is submitted and then JavaScript alert 'Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null in MicrosoftAjax.js' occured and process stops.Files are not loading again.But there is not any 404 error in Network tab.